# Using Types in Angular 2 with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following method in my AppComponent:

```
connectToTweetStream() {
  this._tweetService.connectToStream()
    .subscribe(
      tweet => {
        this.tweets.push(tweet);
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
}
```

When I declare `tweets` as an array of any: `tweets: any[] = [];` at the top of my AppComponent Class everything works great. However, I want `tweets` to be of type `Tweet`, so `tweets: Tweet[] = [];`.

When I make this change I get the error `Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tweet'`. And indeed when I hover over `tweet` on line 4 of the code above it is of type `{}`. How can I fix this so that `tweets` can be an array of `Tweet` objects?

Answer (score 0):

In your subscription cast the type of each item

```
    subscribe(
      (tweet as Tweet) => {
        this.tweets.push(tweet);
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
```